# Stopping python from running certain sections of code if an object is deleted

Tags: python, object, del

When the player enters the letter 'w' the players' z value increases by one and the enemy x value increases by 0.5. I want the enemy object to be deleted when the player enters the letter 'e' and to have the z value increase when pressed w is pressed as normal. How do I get python to ignore certain sections of code if an object is deleted?

```
class Enemy:
    x = 1


play = True
z = 1
while play:
    command = input('')
    if command == 'e':
        del Enemy
    if command == 'w':
        z += 1
        print(z)
    if z >= Enemy.x:
        # stop this from being executed after e is pressed
        Enemy.x += 0.5
        print(Enemy.x)
```

Comment: You cannot manually delete objects in Python (`del thing` just unbinds a variable), and you should not try to use deleting objects as a trigger or condition for anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use booleans like this:

```
class Enemy:
    x = 1

play = True
z = 1
deleted = False
while play:
    command = input('')
    if command == 'e':
        del Enemy
        deleted = True
    if command == 'w':
        z += 1
        print(z)
    if z >= Enemy.x and not deleted:
        Enemy.x += 0.5
        print(Enemy.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to delete classes. Instead, you can create a game context that stores the state of your game. This will contain an enemy object (which can be `None` if the enemy is deleted) and other variables related to the specific game. Then to start the game, you create a new Game instance and pass it a new Enemy instance. This will allow you to grow you game in a more maintainable way:

```
class Enemy:
    x = 1

class Game:
    def __init__(self, enemy):
        self.enemy = enemy
        self.play = True
        self.z = 1

game = Game(Enemy()) # new game with fresh state (enemy, z, etc)

while game.play:
    command = input('')
    if command == 'e':
        game.enemy = None
    if command == 'w':
        game.z += 1
        print(game.z)
    if game.enemy is not None  and game.z >= game.enemy.x:
        # stop this from being executed after e is pressed
        game.enemy.x += 0.5
        print(game.enemy.x)
```

You could probably improve the above by making the things in the loop methods of the Game class. And, instead of directly manipulating `game.enemy.x`, give the `enemy` class a method for increasing score. That will allow different enemies to have different behavior, etc...

Comment: On subject of deletion, I do think `Enemy` instances ought to have a `__del__` method that prints something suitably dramatic though :)